# How to create dropdownlist in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a query like bellow code I am new to ASP.Net MVC:

```
 var MyCompanies = _context.MyCompanyInfoContext.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).OrderBy(o => o.CompanyName);
```

How to generate drop down list in view

my view code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CompanyId, new SelectListItem(ViewBag.MyCompanies))
```

but I get errors

> 'SelectListItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: `new SelectList(ViewBag.MyCompanies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName"))` assuming `MyCompanyInfoContext` contains properties `CompanyId` and `CompanyName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try code bellow this should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(ViewBag.MyCompanies, "Id", "CompanyName"), "- Please Select -", new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control " })
```